# Symfony Doctrine Listener after Security Token populated

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, listener

Still living the dream of Symfony 4.  Not sure if I have the best solution here, but it works.

Doctrine listeners are called very early, before the security bundles has populated the token of the user.  I have a doctrine listener that injects the current user into the table row when the user modifies or creates a table row.  To get this to work I have created a kernel.controller listener that injects the token.storage into the Doctrine Listener.  As the kernel.controller listener is called late, the token.storage if set will be available.

Doctrine Listener

```
class UserTrackListener implements EventSubscriber
{
/**
 * @var null|UserInterface
 */
private $currentUser;

/**
 * @var Request
 */
private $request;

/**
 * @var TokenStorageInterface
 */
private $tokenStorage;

/**
 * @param TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage
 * @param Request              $request
 */
public function injectTokenStorage(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage = null, Request $request = null)
{
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;

    $this->request = $request;

    $this->getCurrentUser();
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    // Tells the dispatcher that you want to listen on the form.pre_submit
    // event and that the preSubmit method should be called.
    return [
        'prePersist',
        'preUpdate'
    ];
}

/**
 * @return null|UserInterface
 */
private function getCurrentUser(): ?UserInterface
{
    if (is_null($this->tokenStorage->getToken()))
        return null;

    $this->currentUser = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

    return $this->currentUser;
}

/**
 * @param LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs
 */
public function prePersist(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
{
    $this->modifyRow($eventArgs);
}

/**
 * @param LoadClassMetadataEventArgs $eventArgs
 */
public function preUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
{
    $this->modifyRow($eventArgs);
}


/**
 * @param $args
 */
private function modifyRow(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
        //The magic happens here...
}   
}
```

and the Kernel.Controller Listener

```
class PageListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
/**
 * @return array
 */
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        KernelEvents::CONTROLLER => ['beforeController', 16]
    ];
}

/**
 * @var TokenStorageInterface
 */
private $tokenStorage;

/**
 * @var RequestStack
 */
private $requestStack;

/**
 * @var UserTrackListener
 */
private $userTrackListener;

/**
 * InstallListener constructor.
 *
 * @param EntityManagerInterface $entityManager
 * @param ContainerInterface     $container
 */
public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, RequestStack $requestStack, UserTrackListener $userTrackListener)
{
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    $this->userTrackListener = $userTrackListener;
}

/**
 * @param PostResponseEvent|GetResponseEvent $event
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function beforeController($event)
{
    $this->userTrackListener->injectTokenStorage($this->tokenStorage, $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest());
}
}
```

Does anyone know of any better (less impact) solution to this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine listeners are called whenever corresponding event occurs. Initialization of them may occur before security context, in this case you should inject `TokenStorageInterface` object in the constructor without getting user object. Then, inside event handler method just retrieve current user instance from the storage.

Comment: Nope, The TokenStorageInterface is injected un-populated if your do that, and never is updated with the current user token. Toke always NULL.  That is how I started.

Comment: Try to call `$this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser()` inside `modifyRow()` method, not inside the constructor.